# Black screen with pointer visible in gnome with fglrx

Tags: gnome, fglrx, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu-gnome and tried installing both the repository fglrx driver as well as the new Crimson driver from AMD.  In both cases the driver installs and on reboot I am greeted with a black screen with a visible mouse pointer.  I know gnome-shell is running because I can press Alt-F2 and "r" and press enter and the mouse pointer disappears and re-appears, suggesting that its registering a gnome-shell "restart".

I tried going back down to the terminal and restarting gdm, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

(What version of ubuntu are you running?)

What worked for me was ssh'ing into my box and remove the fglrx drivers. But that only works if you have enabled sshd to run. (You could also try boot to shell and do the same thing.)

I could login with mesa drivers, but then I had a non optimal resolution and everything was slow. I installed the AMD opensource drivers and everything was ok back then.

Comment: Sorry it's ubuntu gnome 15.10.  I was able to drop down to a virtual terminal and remove the fglrx drivers just fine.  But I'd like to get the graphics card working with the proprietary drivers.  It seems to work, except gnome only shows the mouse pointer.  Which I suspect must have something to do with the Mutter not rendering any of the user interface.

Answer (score -2):

Switch Monitor back to whatever it was before install.Proprietary or not,just reset it! It worked for me twice! On Ubuntu 16.04 and Lubuntu 16.04 !